# Install/Uninstall Apache2 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.1

Tags: php, parsing, virtualhost, macos-sierra, apache2.4

Not knowing that my Mac came with Apache2.4 and not having checked which OS I was operating on, I followed this guide to get Apache/MySQL/PHP on my machine using Homebrew: https://echo.co/blog/os-x-109-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew

This led to me having two versions of Apache2 running on my machine: 2.2 and 2.4. When asking in the terminal for which apache was running the answer was 2.4 but when trying to open an instance of my program on my virtual host I could not reach the page.
What happened after that is confused because I got some other people working on it trying to solve it and they changed and moved files around, so when I got my computer back I didn't even know where to start to understand where I was, so I tried to uninstall both apache versions and reinstall 2.4.

Since I couldn't find any guide that helped me uninstalling apache and the brew command remove was not working, I went for erasing the apache folders and I searched for anything in my directories that contained the words "apache" or "httpd" (anything I could find, which means I might also have missed some files cause I just didn't know where to search for them).

After I did that, I reinstalled apache 2.4 following this other guide https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions up to the PHP installation (which I haven't performed).

After installing apache again I inserted the data for my virtual host in httpd-vhost.conf as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin personal@mail.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/username/apache_vh/myApp"
    ServerName myApp.username.com
    ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/myApp-error_log"
    CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/myApp-access_log" common
 <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and then I modified the httpd.conf file in the /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4 folder with the followings (I'm omitting the commented lines):

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/opt/httpd24"
Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/mod_authn_file.so
[...]
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/mod_authz_user.so
[...]
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/mod_auth_basic.so
[...]
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/mod_reqtimeout.so
[...]
LoadModule filter_module libexec/mod_filter.so
[...]
LoadModule mime_module libexec/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/mod_log_config.so
[...]
LoadModule env_module libexec/mod_env.so
[...]
LoadModule headers_module libexec/mod_headers.so
[...]
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/mod_version.so
[...]
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/mod_unixd.so
[...]
LoadModule status_module libexec/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/mod_autoindex.so
[...]
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    #LoadModule cgi_module libexec/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
    #LoadModule cgid_module libexec/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
[...]
LoadModule dir_module libexec/mod_dir.so
[...]
LoadModule alias_module libexec/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User _www
Group staff
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/Users/username/Sites">
    MultiViews
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

     <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>

     CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/access_log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/var/apache2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/var/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/mime.types

    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    #AddHandler type-map var
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

# Virtual hosts
Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

[...]

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Later on I added the following to the hosts file in the /etc folder (which is not the same as /usr/local/etc, this one resides in the root, one level up /usr):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1  myApp.username.com
```

And my hope was to see "it works!" on localhost:8080 and myApp on localhost:80.
I do see "it works!" on localhost:8080 but if I update the page I get "This site can’t be reached/localhost refused to connect.". I have started, stopped, restarted apache but I get this same behaviour all the time.
On localhost:80 instead I get myApp, but I cannot run it, the PHP is not being parsed and I only see the tree structure of the folder.

I ran the apachectl configtest and I get Syntax OK. I ran php -v and I got PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Nov 23 2016 11:12:05) so everything is working.

Checking the httpd.conf file that I pasted above I noticed I was missing the php module, so I added `LoadModule php5_module libexec/libphp5.so`

I am still getting the same problems.

What I really don't seem to understand is the folder structure of all of it, because I am trying to follow other guides but they seem to point to an apache2 folder that I must have erased while I shouldn't have trying to uninstall the older versions and apparently it didn't get recreated during the reinstallation (/etc/apache2/users). I do not have an apache2 folder in my etc folder that I have at the root level, so I assume I have to search for /users in the /etc/apache2 that I have under /usr/local, but in that folder I only have the directory 2.4.

I am extremely confused by the organization of all these directories and files and I don't seem to be able to understand if they have been moved around by the people who tried to help me, if I have accidentally erased that /etc/apache2/users while uninstalling those previous versions or if I just basically messed up following too many different guides.

So my question is:

Can I fix this somehow as it is to show myApp on the port 80 in localhost parsing PHP correctly?

If not, how can I uninstall apache in a clean way, making sure that I don't erase important files that shouldn't be touched and at the same time I take away all the ones that will create a conflict with the newly installed version?

Comment: I also have more than one place where an index.html for the "it works!" message is: 

/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en
  and    
/usr/local/var/www/htdocs/index.html

I tried modifying both of them but I can't succeed in having the text changing, so the public folder apache is referring to when responding on localhost:8080 is neither of the two (or I'm still missing something).

Answer (score 0):

After much research and collaboration, the only way to make Apache work again was to make a factory reset for my OS and get back to the default organisation.
Now my folders look clean and apache is running on the port 80 as it should instead of 8080. I will now proceed in creating a virtual host for myApp.